# How to restore M1.9 database to pre-migration state?

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, magento2.3.3

I'm testing data migration from 1.9.1.0 to 2.3.3 and was wondering if there is a way to restore M1.9 database to pre-migration state somehow without restoring it from backup? Is there some operations that could be done in the database in order to achieve this?

I'm afraid that when I start the migration process with initial data migration and prepare the M2 shop, some new additions in M1.9 installations during the M2 preparation cause the later delta migration to fail and we no longer are able restore M1.9 DB from backup (because we don't want to lose the new data) and migration fails completely. In that case I need a way to restart the migration from the beginning.